# Ionic formgroup patchvalue patch as strings from string array

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

In my component I receive a Card to edit and make a PUT request:

```
constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,) {

    this.cardToEdit = navParams.get('cardToEdit');

    this.editCRCCardForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        thing: ['', Validators.required],
        responsibilities: ['', Validators.required],
        collaborators: [''],
    });
}

ionViewDidLoad() {

    console.log(this.cardToEdit);
    this.editCRCCardForm.patchValue(this.cardToEdit);

    ...

}

updateCard(formData){

    console.log(formData)
}
```

console prints (which is the Card to edit):

```
{"id":8,"responsibilities":[{"id":7,"name":"Name","card":8},{"id":8,"name":"ISBN","card":8}],"collaborators":[{"id":4,"name":"","card":8}],"thing":"Book"}
```

The form to edit the card:

```
<form [formGroup]="editCRCCardForm" (ngSubmit)="updateCard(editCRCCardForm.value)" autocomplete="off">
    <!-- Title -->

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Thing*</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="thing"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Attributes and operations*</ion-label>
        <ion-textarea formControlName="responsibilities"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Related things</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="collaborators"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>



    <button ion-button full type="submit" [disabled]="!editCRCCardForm.valid">Add</button>
</form>
```

Now my patchValue corrrectly puts Book in the thing field, but for other two fields I get [object Object] in my template.

How can I fix that? E.g. I essentially want to populate `Name ISBN` in responsibilities (in the textarea, values separated by space)

**UPDATE:**

I tried something like

```
ionViewDidLoad() {

        this.editCRCCardForm.patchValue({thing: this.cardToEdit.thing});

        for (let responsibility of this.cardToEdit.responsibilities){

            this.editCRCCardForm.patchValue({responsibilities: responsibility.name}); 

        }

    }
```

Which is partially successful printing only the last value in the array i.e. ISBN and not NAME ISBN

Comment: Both `responsibilities` and `collaborators` are arrays not strings. Not sure what you were expecting?

Comment: Yes I know but is there a way to patch the values of an array to a form field?

Comment: I think it is patched. Its not showing in your form as the value is not the expected string

Comment: you will have to manually set the name.

Comment: I tried by adding [value]="" but it didn't help. Could you perhaps show an example?

Comment: Its not clear what you want to print.. they are both arrays with possibly multiple objects and you have one input each

Comment: I just want to print their (responsibilities's or collborators's) name properties whose values as I mentioned are e.g. Name, ISBN